# Accessing Elastic Search from another machine in same network

Tags: elasticsearch

So I'm trying to configure Elastic Search to be able to access it from another machine in my network.
I've been searching and trying different things but none of them is working.

Already configured firewall and I set `network.host: 0.0.0.0` on `elasticsearch.yml` file. But still can't get access on `[ES_host_ip]:9200` from the other machine.

Comment: Is ES started and running ? Are you able to ping the other machine on the network ?

Comment: Ya ES is running and i can ping the other machine